# Rendering of a string in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like some help with the following:

I have life course data on family formation, and I would like to create a figure of the data in Excel. I have a row for each individual, with 15 columns that represent a specific time point (age).

For each column (time point) I have a specific state where a person can be in. For instance 1=living with parents, 2=living alone, 3=married, and so on.

My data looks like this.

[example data]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89989773/Untitled.jpg

What I would like Excel to do is represent the data as they are, but use a specific color for each state. Thus 1=green, 2=blue, 3=red, etc.

The plot should like a bit like this

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89989773/plot.png

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a spec for project development rather than a question. Please narrow down your topic to a specific question. Regards,

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. It does indeed what I am looking for, but I would like to render it in a graph. Would that be possible?

Comment: I have tried several graphs, but it did not provide the output I was intereted in. As you can see I provided detailed information in my question with how the data are formatted and what kind of output I would like. So basically a bar graph with conditional formats. I don't see why this is a 'blind request' that isn't suited for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You could conditional format those cells (doesn't need to be programmatically done).
Each `Cell.Interior` has an Index (I recommend the use of `ColorIndex`).
You could scan the entire Worksheet in order to find such Indexes and then build the chart you want.